# What is #= in Prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd

The operator `#=` is mentioned on some page, e.g. https://www.metalevel.at/prolog but not on most other pages, e.g.: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=operators

What does this operator mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Operators are simply syntactical sugar for predicates: if you write `X #= Y`, it is short for `#=(X,Y)`, so lookup the predicate `(#=)/2`.

The operator is mentioned as a predicate in the [*SWI-Prolog documentation*](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%23%3D%20/%202):

> The arithmetic expression `X` equals `Y`. When reasoning over **integers**, replace [`(is)/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(is)/2) by [`(#=)/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%23%3D%20/%202) to obtain more general relations. See declarative integer arithmetic (section [A.8.3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd-integer-arith)).

They are part of the *Constraint Logic Programming on Finite Domains* (CLP(FD)) package. One advantage of this *constraint* over the `(is)/2` operator, is that it can be used in multiple directions. For instance:

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
true.

?- 4 #= 2*Y.
Y = 2.

?- X #= 2*16.
X = 32.
```

Furthermore, constraints can be delayed. For example:

```
?- X #= 2*Y, Y #= 14.
X = 28,
Y = 14.
```

For a more extensive introduction read 
[this clpfd primer by @mat](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/clpfd.html).

Comment: With SWI Prolog version 8.3.24 after the module charged all the examples give an error: Operator expected. Any solutions? Thxs.